# WordPress Function and Shortcode to show first workday of the month

Tags: php, wordpress, date, wordpress-shortcode

What I'd like to do is display the date of the first workday of a month unless it's past, then show the next months first workday on a WordPress website using a shortcode.

I'm thinking this could be done as a function in the WordPress Theme's functions.php file. I have a shortcode function I've been using to show the current year for Copyright notices in the footer.

```
function year_shortcode() {
  $year = date('Y');
  return $year;
}
add_shortcode('year', 'year_shortcode');
```

And I have a PHP function that is supposed to show the first weekday of a month and year.

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime('weekday february 2016'))
```

But I don't know how to put it all together. I was thinking something like this:

1. Get the current day, month and year variables.
2. Put them in the PHP date above.
3. If the resulting date is past the current date add 1 to the month and run again.
4. Put the result in the shortcode function.

This is the first time I've posted on here and I'm not a programmer. Please be kind and thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: for number 1 you could do this. I am not good at dates but this might help

$timestamp = strtotime('weekday february 2016');
$month = date('m',$timestamp  );
$year = date('Y', $timestamp );
$day = date('d', $timestamp );

Answer (score 0):

You can put it all together like this.

```
function year_shortcode( $args ) {
    $first_workday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('weekday'));
    return $first_workday;
}
add_shortcode('year', 'year_shortcode');
```

and use this [year] shortcode anywhere.

Comment: That's 90% of the way there. It works, but I also need the logic in #3 above. For instance today it outputs 1-3-2021 but I need it to out put the first workday of the next month since 1-3-2021 is now in the past.

Comment: Ok i will back to you.

Comment: This updated code breaks the site. The previous code worked, I just needed some PHP logic to check if the returned date was before the current day, and if so get the first workday of the next month. Does that make sense?

Comment: There is no error on that code. did you check the error logs?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out with improved code and the conditional I requested in #3 above.

```
function payment_date( $args ) {
    $first_weekday = date( 'm-d-Y', strtotime( 'first weekday this month' ) );
    $first_weekday_next = date( 'm-d-Y', strtotime( 'first weekday next month' ) );
    
    if($first_workday < strtotime('0:00')) {
        return $first_weekday;
    } else {
        return $first_weekday_next;
    }
}
add_shortcode('payment', 'payment_date');
```

I'm using the PHP relative formats (first weekday of this month/first weekday of next month) instead of dates. Then the conditional if the result is in the past, get the first workday from the next month. Note: the 0:00 is so just the date is being compared and not the time.